# Fragments: Remove all fragments in a view

Tags: android, android-fragments

The scenario I am faced with, is in my application I have a *single pane* and *dual pane* style layout. Rather than individually handle every single navigation operation possible between the screens, for every different style of layout, I am using a function which sets up the layout correctly when given the desired screen.

It is basically a `switch` statement for each screen in the app, with a nested `switch` statement in each screen to handle each layout style. This is what I'm talking about in code:

```
protected void setupScreen() {
    switch(currentScreen) {
    case SCREEN_ONE:
        switch(currentLayout) {
        case SINGLE_PANE:
            // Perform actions to setup the screen
            break;
        case DUAL_PANE:
            // Perform actions to setup the screen
            break;
        }
        break;
    case SCREEN_TWO:
        switch(currentLayout) {
        case SINGLE_PANE:
            // Perform actions to setup the screen
            break;
        case DUAL_PANE:
            // Perform actions to setup the screen
            break;
        }
        break
    // ... etc ....
    }
}
```

In the section where I want to *perform the actions to setup the screen*, this consists of the following basic three operations:

```
// Create the fragments if necessary
if (screenFragment == null) {
    screenFragment = new myFragment();
}

// Remove the existing fragments from the layout views
// HOW???

// Add the fragments for this screen to the view
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(pane1.getId(), myFragment, "myFragment").commit();
```

As you can see, what I am struggling with is **how** to do the second step. **How** do you remove all `Fragment`s from a given `View` without knowing exactly which ones you are wanting to remove? The closest I have found is `FragmentTransaction.replace()` which does successfully do this for every case **but** when it turns out you are replacing a `Fragment` with the same fragment. In this case, it does not remove all, then add (like the documentation suggests), it just seems to remove. Is this an issue with using the compatibility libraries or is it not the way `FragmentTransaction.replace()` should be used?

In any case, how should I go about doing this? Do I have to code a `removeAllFragments()` function to go through every fragment and detach it or is there a way to do the first half of what the 'two in one' `FragmentTransaction.replace()` function claims to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The typical mechanism is to use [`FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentByTag(java.lang.String)) . You use this and add tags to your fragments (or the alternative for id's). This way you can determine what fragments are currently being managed. Then, once you have a handle to a present fragment (findFragmentByTag returns non-null), you can use [`FragmentManager.beginTransaction()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#beginTransaction()) to start a FragmentTransaction and remove / add the necessary fragments. Working in this way will allow you to avoid the 're-adding' process for the fragment you want to keep.

What I'd probably do is have code like so: (warning psuedo code)

```
Fragment pane1 = FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("myFragmentPane1");
Fragment pane2 = FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("myFragmentPane2");

setupScreen(pane1, pane2);
```

You should also consider sub-classes of your class instead of having 'everything in one class'. You have a fairly obvious case of Martin Fowler's [Replace Conditional with Subclass](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html). Otherwise, I fear this is going to be incredibly hard to manager when you add another screen.

Comment: +1, sounds dumb, but have never thought of using the Tag to identify where the fragment is placed, always used it to identify what type the fragment is

Answer (score 20):

None of the other answers were really working for me. Here's what I did:

```
List<Fragment> al = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
if (al == null) {
   // code that handles no existing fragments
   return;
}

for (Fragment frag : al)
{
   // To save any of the fragments, add this check.
   // A tag can be added as a third parameter to the fragment when you commit it
   if (frag == null || frag.getTag().equals("<tag-name>")) {
      continue;
   }

   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(frag).commit(); 
}
```

or, if you're forced to use it (but not recommended):

```
.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Also, if you're removing all fragments from the view multiple times, you might consider checking if the current frag is null or `isDetached()` or `isRemoving()` or you might get `NullPointerExceptions`.

**Update**: The documentation for `getSupportFragmentManger().getFragments()` is apparently [hidden](https://code.google.com/p/doclava/wiki/JavadocTags#@hide) now, but still works just fine in my code. Here's the screenshot of the documentation:

[image]

Having said that, since it is hidden, they no longer want this method used, so see my update below.

**Update 8-4-15**: If you're not using the support library for fragments, there is unfortunately no `getFragments()` available, but there are still a couple, more inconvenient, options.

1. Give each `fragment` a `tag` or `id` upon creation, and iterate through them to process each `fragment` as desired.
2. Create a listener using `onAttachListener` so each time a new `fragment` is attached to the `activity`, you can store that `fragment`, and then iterate through that data structure to process each `fragment` as desired.

When not using the `getSupportFragmentManager()`, to process a transaction you will need to use `getFragmentManager()` instead.

Comment: Actually, there is; it's just been hidden since this answer was written. And it still works. Try it.

Comment: It's not true. It's presented only in support library since 4.3, however it's not presented in android.app.FragmentManager. Answer is leading in wrong direction and applicable only for support library (with additional mentions about usage of hidden API).

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize you were talking about using the normal `FragmentManager`, rather than the `SupportFragmentManager`. You're right; there is no `getFragments()` for `android.app.FragmentManager`. See my updated answer.

Comment: your code have a few Exceptions pit falls, it is better to add the following if's:    if(al != null && al.size()>0)     And   if (frag.getTag() != null)

Comment: I disagree. I check first if `al == null` and handle that; I'll add a return;. I don't need to check if `ai.size() > 0` because the for loop handles that. If it's empty, the inner code is never run, which should also mean that the `frag != null`, but that is a good idea to check, as the programmer might make a mistake there.

Answer (score 3):

If you use **android.support.v4.app.Fragment** you can do this:

```
List<Fragment> fragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
if (fragments != null) {
    for (Fragment fragment : fragments) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work? it says it requires `android.app.Fragment`

Comment: @KahnKah ... you have to use `getFragmentManager()` in your use case

Answer (score 1):

Turns out `FragmentTransaction.replace()` is the correct operation and should work correctly. It only does not work when using `ActionBarSherlock` and `SherlockFragmentActivity` so I can only assume it is a bug in this compatibility library.

I have confirmed this through using the code below to implement the desired behaviour through Android on API11+, the android compatibility library, and ActionBarSherlock. It only breaks in the last instance.

```
package com.test.test;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
  // Consistent fragment instance
    myFragment myFrag = null;

    // Views
    FrameLayout fl = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        Button b = new Button(this);
        b.setText("Repeat");
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Reattach the same fragment
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(fl.getId(), myFrag).commit();

            }
        });

        fl = new FrameLayout(this);
        fl.setId(200);
        fl.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        myFrag = new myFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(fl.getId(), myFrag).commit();

        ll.addView(b);
        ll.addView(fl);

        setContentView(ll);
    }

    public static class myFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
            tv.setText("My fragment");
            tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

            return tv;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more or less how I have handled this. Have all your fragments implement an interface something like:

```
public interface NamedFragment{

    public FragmentName getFragmentName();

}
```

Make an enum corresponding to your fragments:

```
public enum FragmentName{

    SOME_FRAGMENT,
    SOME_OTHER_FRAGMENT;

}
```

Then in your fragment switching activity:

```
// Get the manager and transaction separately so you can use both: 
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

// Get a reference to the fragment(s) currently in the container(s)
    Fragment currentFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(position);

    FragmentName cFragmentName =
            ((NamedFragment) currentFragment).getFragmentName();
    Fragment nextFragment =
            Fragment.instantiate(this, some_new_fragment_string);
    FragmentName nFragmentName =
            ((NamedFragment) nextFragment).getFragmentName();
// Compare the "names"
    if(cFragmentName != nFragmentName){
        ft.replace(position, nextFragment);
    }
```

You'll have to change things around a little to fit your particulars.

Comment: My answer makes sense if you only ever want one instance of a given class at a time; @Nick's makes sense if you need unique identifiers for each instance.