# Android : How to remove fragments from fragment manager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I am developing Android App.
In a single activity I am replacing fragments.
After some iterations my app gets closed without any force close message and no exception.

While searching I got one thing.
If I track number of fragments on fragment manager using

```
getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().size()
```

it keeps on incrementing while there is only one fragment which is active and no fragment present in back stack as I am replacing fragments.

Example :

- Frag 1 > Frag 2: No of fragments is 2
- Frag 1 > Frag 2 > Frag 3: No of fragments is 3
- Frag 1 > Frag 2 > Frag 3 > Frag 2 > Frag 1: No of fragments is 3

Here is code which I am using for fragment transaction:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content, fragmentStep1,
                    ApplicationTags.FRAGMENT_TAG_PAGE_1)
            .disallowAddToBackStack().commit();
    getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

I need to remove all these fragments from fragentmanager for reducing memory usage by app.

Please help me with this one.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: similiar to this please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14764043/fragments-remove-all-fragments-in-a-view

Answer (score 1):

Try to `getFragmentManager().popBackStack();` after `.commit()`

Comment: It's always better to include an explanation when providing a code based answer...

Comment: @2Dee In many cases it's my principal position. Full code example deprives questioner a possible thinking. And i think that my answer is full.

Answer (score 0):

If it was a memory issue you would get an OOM error in your Log. The code you posted is correct. The issue must be something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of fragments on BackStack by 
    getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

as you are replacing fragments and not saving the previous fragment on BackStack, there will be exactly one fragment at a time. So the issue is not with fragments.

Comment: so, if there is exactly 1 fragment, is `getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();` should be 0? or it should be 1?

Answer (score 0):

You could remove all fragments when they reach a certain number.

```
// set your own max stack size
MAX_STACK_SIZE = 20;

int stackSize = getBackStackEntryCount;
if(stackSize>20)
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
for(int i = 0; i < stackSize; ++i) {
    fm.popBackStackImmediate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, if you run through your ArrayList of fragments returned by `getFragments()` you will see, that all of them are **null** except the one which is in fact active. So it is not the issue.

(That is what happened the time I tried to figure out why there seemed to be more active fragments in my activity than I had expected)