# Remove all fragments from container

Tags: android, android-fragments

Is there a way to remove all fragments which are already added the specific view with its view id?

For example I want to remove all fragments which are added into R.id.fragmentcontainer view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fragments: Remove all fragments in a view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14764043/fragments-remove-all-fragments-in-a-view)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Its very simple just loop through all the fragments and remove it

```
for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
}
```

But in case of **Navigation Drawer** be sure to check it, if you try to remove it you will get error.

```
for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
  if (fragment instanceof NavigationDrawerFragment) {
      continue;
  }
  else { 
      getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
  }
}
```

Last but very **important** be sure to check for null before doing any fragment transactions

```
for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
    if (fragment instanceof NavigationDrawerFragment) {
        continue;
    }
    else if (fragment != null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What is `NavigationDrawerFragment`? It will be useful, but I think, it is from some library.

Comment: NavigationDrawerFragment is simply a fragment added as nav drawer. It is not from any other library.

Comment: I faced a situation where a FragmentTransaction `add` creates a normal fragment, while `replace` makes tall toolbar over it (at Lollipop, with navigation drawer). Maybe you are right, it would be good to create a dummy fragment and `add` others. Have you done so?

Comment: yes i always prefer adding fragment as navigation drawer, it gives more control over design and changes

Comment: Beware, this will remove **ALL** fragments in the given fragment manager. Not just in a particular layout container as OP was asking

Comment: I think you can use reuse existing transaction while removing fragments in the loop, no need to begin new one every time.

Answer (score 16):

In case someone is looking for a code in Kotlin:

```
supportFragmentManager.apply {
        for (fragment in fragments) {
           beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit()
        }
        popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

It is indeed very simple.

```
private static void removeAllFragments(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    while (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
    }
}
```

Comment: This only works if the fragment is added to backstack

Answer (score 6):

More optimized version
There is no need in multiple call of commit so lets call it one time at the end

```
supportFragmentManager.fragments.let {
    if (it.isNotEmpty()) {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
            for (fragment in it) {
                remove(fragment)
            }
            commit()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this code

```
activity?.let {
it.supportFragmentManager.fragments.forEach { fragment ->
        it.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit()
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Save all your fragments in an ArrayList.

Initializing:

```
List<Fragment> activeCenterFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
```

Adding fragment to list:

```
private void addCenterFragments(Fragment fragment) {
    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.empty_center_layout, fragment);
    activeCenterFragments.add(fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

When you want to remove **all** them, do the following:

```
private void removeActiveCenterFragments() {
    if (activeCenterFragments.size() > 0) {
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        for (Fragment activeFragment : activeCenterFragments) {
            fragmentTransaction.remove(activeFragment);
        }
        activeCenterFragments.clear();
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

I have used this method in production for years, and it works like a charm. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: This won't work if the state has been restored after your app has been killed as the list will be empty.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, hope it helps :D

```
try {
if(manager.getFragments()!=null){
    if(manager.getBackStackEntryCount()>0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < manager.getBackStackEntryCount(); i++)
            manager.popBackStack();

        manager.beginTransaction().remove(getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.main_content))
        .commit();
        }
    }
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This check is unnecessary:
  " if(manager.getBackStackEntryCount()>0) { "
since it will never run a pass on the for loop anyway if this is false.

Answer (score 2):

This Kotlin extension does the job:

```
fun FragmentManager.removeAll(containerId: Int) {
    beginTransaction().apply {
        fragments.filter {
            it.id == containerId
        }.forEach {
            remove(it)
        }
    }.commit()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is much simplier way to clear all fragments from Fragment Container View

```
view.findViewById(R.id.fragmentcontainer).removeAllViews()
```

if you are using viewbinding then

```
binding.fragmentcontainer.removeAllViews()
```

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to useful answers I have to say that if you have added few fragments to specific view container, for example:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .add(containerViewId, fragmentA)
    .add(containerViewId, fragmentB)
    .commit();
```

and if you need just replace them by one, you can simply call `replace` without removing *fragmentA* and *fragmentB*

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(containerViewId, fragment)
    .commit();
```

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#replace(int,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%20extends%20androidx.fragment.app.Fragment%3E,%20android.os.Bundle,%20java.lang.String)) `replace` removes all fragments before adding new:

> Replace an existing fragment that was added to a container. This is
> essentially the same as calling remove(Fragment) for all currently
> added fragments that were added with the same containerViewId and then
> add(int, Fragment, String) with the same arguments given here.

Comment: this is not correct way. cause you couldnt remove all fragments from the container. you only remove the fragment from the back stack which added last